# Change Set with Record Type Changes Deploys Succesfully But Doesn't Actually Update Anything

Tags: deployment, change-set, platform-bug

I'm trying to migrate some record type changes to help keep my sandboxes in sync, but they aren't getting deployed.

I've confirmed the deployment succeeds, but none of my changes come through, and the last modified date on the record type hasn't been updated.

I've noticed the metadata for a custom object includes the record type details, but I don't want to deploy the entire object.

Any tips on how to properly deploy record types?

Comment: This question has been around for quite a while, so figure you've already moved on. But if you haven't it would be great if you could post the specific details about what you were trying to deploy, and any xml. Sounds like this was a bug, but hard to say without more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Record types are related to several things including the picklists on an Object, `Business process`, the `RecordTypeId` field on an Object, the `RecordType object` and probably more that isn't coming to mind like the `RecordTypeLocalization` Object which may or may not apply to your custom object. If you've added picklist values or changed the Business Process, you're going to need to sync the Object too. It sounds as though you're aware of that. It may be simplest to just recreate the record type changes in your org.

Answer (score 0):

RecordTypes can be deployed with change sets (meaning the in browser ui for building deployments) as well as with the metadata api.

If you're not seeing the changes you've made deployed to another sandbox there may be a bug that's worth sending to salesforce. You also might considering editing your post to be more specific about what changes weren't getting deployed so the community could try and replicate your issue and suggest workarounds or clarifications about the limitations of deployments.